# Difficulty using variadic template class member functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

Difficulty using variadic template class member functions.  Pt is a simple struct

```
template<unsigned char D>  struct Pt
{
  int d[D];
};

template<class T, unsigned char D, unsigned char ... RestD> class MArray
{
public:

   T& operator()(const Pt<D>& p, RestD... args)
   {
      return m_data[1]; // junk return until I get the args right
   }
   T* m_data;
};
```

I keep getting with clang++

```
>clang++ -std=c++11 variadicMArray.cpp
 variadicMArray.cpp:70:33: error: unknown type name 'RestD'
 T& operator()(const Pt<D>& p, RestD... args)
                               ^
```

It won't recognize my RestD as a pattern.   I think I'm doing something rather simple wrong here.

Comment: `RestD` is **not** (packed) *type*. It is (packed) *value* of type `unsigned char` as per the class template parameters.

Comment: So what changes in the syntax ?   I want operator() to take a signature that reflects the class definition specified in RestD

Comment: So how does one use a packed value ?   every example I see is with a packed type.